# How to make the result set of two digit in the SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following query but the results in distance are more than one digit, I want it to be 2 digit only.

```
UPDATE Customer 
SET Distance = CAST(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(distance, 'km' , '' ), 'miles', '')as float) * 1.3 * 0.62137 AS NVARCHAR) + 'Miles' 
FROM customer
```

If I have result like `2.3434453433` then I want it to change to `2.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach :**

**[Here is SQLFiddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17f44/1)** for Approach

```
select Convert(varchar(3),convert(numeric(5,1),(2.3434453433)))
```

**Solution :**

```
UPDATE Customer 
   set Distance= Convert(varchar(3),Convert(Numeric(5,1),
                    CAST(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(distance, 'km' , '' ),
                   'miles', '')as float) * 1.3 * 0.62137 AS NVARCHAR))) + 'Miles'
```

Comment: can you give me a `distance` value present in Table

Comment: You can Change `numeric(2,1)` to `numeric(10,1)`. If Integer part is of 2 digit then this will give an error

Comment: 0.7Miles
4.45Miles
1.32Miles
2.28Miles
0.99Miles
0.57Miles

Comment: Ok.. Got It! Actually it was 2.3 as Numeric and "Miles' as varchar and It was trying to sum those values. Now I have Edited My Answer Check It.

Comment: that worked but on question if integer part is of 2 digit then should i make it with (10, 1)..

Comment: Not necessory, You can keep it to `(2,1)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33190/discussion-between-novicetodotnet-and-rj1990)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the round function if you the round value

```
UPDATE Customer set Distance=
    CAST(round(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(distance, 'km' , '' ), 'miles', '')as float) * 1.3 * 0.62137,1) AS NVARCHAR) 
    + 'Miles' FROM customer
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
CAST(CAST(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(distance, 'km' , '' ), 'miles', '')as float) * 1.3 * 0.62137 AS DECIMAL(19,1)) AS NVARCHAR) 
+ 'Miles' FROM customer
```

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear to me why you would want to *store* the value as a string instead of just formatting it on output.

Your expression seems a bit confused, multiplying by 1.3 and multiplying by 0.62.  I think you want something like this:

```
UPDATE Customer
    set Distance = (case when right(distance, 3) = ' km'
                         then replace(str(cast(left(distance, charindex(' ', distance) - 1),
                                       as float)/0.62137, 6, 1), ' ', '') + 'Miles'
                         else distance
                    end)
```

The [`str()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx) converts a number to a specified string format with a given length and precision.

However, it seems like you really should change the `Customer` table to have a distance, a unit, and a "DistanceMiles" field, which is computed column combining the values from the other two.  It would be something like:

```
    DistanceMiles as (case when Units = 'Mile' 
                           then replace(str(Distance, 6, 1), ' ', '')+' Miles'
                           when Units = 'km'
                           then replace(str(Distance/0.62137, 6, 1), ' ', '')+' Miles'
                      end)
```